# Automatic file numbering in ggsave as in png

Tags: r, ggplot2, printf

In `png()`, the first argument is `filename = "Rplot%03d.png"` which causes files to be generated with ascending numbers. However, in `ggsave,` this doesn't work, the number always stays at the lowest number (Rplots001.png") and this file is always overwritten.

Looking at the code of the grDevices-functions (e.g. `grDevices::png()` it appears that the automatic naming happens in functions which are called by `.External()`

Is there already an implementation of this file naming functionality in R such that it is accessible outside of the grDevices functions?

Edit:
asked differently, is there a way to continue automatic numbering after shutting off and restarting a device? For example, in this code, the two later files overwrite the former ones:

```
png(width = 100)
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
png(width = 1000)
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to do this. For example, how about simply adding a time stamp.  something like:

```
fname = function(basename = 'myfile', fileext = 'png'){
  paste(basename, format(Sys.time(), " %b-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S."), fileext, sep="")
}

ggsave(fname())
```

Or, if you prefer sequential numbering, then something along the lines of

```
next_file = function(basename = 'myfile', fileext = 'png', filepath = '.'){
  old.fnames = grep(paste0(basename,' \\d+\\.', fileext,'$'), 
    list.files(filepath), value = T)
  lastnum = gsub(paste0(basename,' (\\d+)\\.', fileext,'$'), '\\1', old.fnames)
  if (!length(lastnum)) { 
    lastnum = 1 
  } else {
    lastnum = sort(as.integer(lastnum),T)[1] + 1L 
  }
  return(paste0(basename, ' ', sprintf('%03i', lastnum), '.', fileext))
}

ggsave(next_file())
```

Comment: Thanks, I would have done something like that, my question was rather if this function exists already (since this functionality was obviously already implemented before, namely in the grDevices functions :) ) and if I can avoid writing one on my own ;)

Comment: There are no base functions to do this, which is why I showed you how to implement it yourself.  Maybe it exists in some package, but I'm not aware of one.  The closest base function is `tempfile`, which does have an option to specify the directory to save in, but does not provide sequential numbering.